# Allowing the user to acknowledge a UILocalNotification without launching the app

Tags: cocoa-touch, uilocalnotification

Is there any way, when a `UILocalnotification` is displayed as an alert, for there to only be one action button displayed, rather than both "Close" and "Launch"?

Assuming there is no way, I can change the second action button to say "Continue". I want to be able to register in my app that they did press "Continue" but I don't want the app to actually launch. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible within current SDK, unfortunately. The push notification alert can have only two actions – either it's cancelled and your application is not notified, or your application is being brought to foreground to handle the notification.

Comment: What is not possible exactly?